# How to remove mobile device user's token from Owin server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin, bearer-token

I have a problem about **removing bearer token** from Owin server. My plan is when mobile device user clicked Signout button then user token must removing from my owin server. Is there any  solution for this? If your answer no, I can change my idea and i open to different ideas.

Here is my Startup.cs:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

        ConfigureOAuth(app);
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7), 
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,                          
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
            RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider()  
        };
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());            
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that you are having with this is that the bearer token lives on the client side so there really isn't much of a way to do it from your end.  The only way to de-authenticate the user in OAuth is to remove the token on the client side.

There are other ways that you could go about it such as creating a custom user session.  Check out this blog post for a more detailed description on how to do so: http://www.nakov.com/blog/2014/12/22/webapi-owin-identity-custom-login-service/

Another method you could go about this is shortening the lifespan of the token to a considerably short time.  This could have close to the same effect but I doubt is what you are looking for.

Comment: Okay. I tried Authentication.SignOut function but it didnt work well. I will try remove the token on the client side or change ExpireTime to shorter. Thanks..

Comment: Sounds good, let me know if it doesn't work and I'll dig into it a little more for you.

Comment: I forgot it sorry. This solution worked for me. Thanks.